# Configure HEC to Use User Provided Certificate - Splunk Cloud

Tags: splunk

I am forwarding events from a DBaaS to a Splunk instance hosted on Cloud.

1. Provisioned a Splunk Cloud instance (free trial license).
2. Created a new index in the instance I just created.
3. Created a new HTTP Endpoint Collector (HEC) forwarding metrics to the new index created.

I verified that the HEC was online with the following:

```
curl -k "https://***-*-*****.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector" \
-H "Authorization: Splunk ${splunk_token}" \
-d '{"event": "Hello, world!", "sourcetype": "manual"}'
```

All good.

The HEC includes a self-signed certificate by default. That just won't work for me. I can't find a way to configure it to use a custom cert. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by creating a custom app and including the HEC info in an inputs.conf file along with your certificate chain.  See https://community.splunk.com/t5/All-Apps-and-Add-ons/How-do-I-secure-the-event-collector-port-8088-with-an-ssl/m-p/243885 for more info.  The thread is old, but most of the information still applies.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I am a Splunk idiot. This will be a bit of a lift for me. I'll give it a try though and loop back.